# twillio sending message via Browser

Tags: django, twilio

I have implemented a Django app for sending SMS via browser, The app is working fine when I have a custom message defined from the codes.
The issue is that the view codes cannot read the message input from the browser for sending.

**VIEWS CODE**

```
def pastor_send(request):  
  #recepient=Ministry.objects.all()
  template_name='corecode/pastor.html'
  if request.method=='GET':
    message=request.GET.get('sms')
    client = Client(settings.ACCOUNT_SID,settings.AUTH_TOKEN)
    message = client.messages \
                .create(
                     body=message,
                     from_='+somenumber',
                     to='somenumber'
                 )
    return render(request,template_name)
  return HttpResponse("Message sent Succesfully",200)
```

**HTML CODE**

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{%block title%}
    Send to Ministry Pastors
{%endblock%}

{%block content%}

<h4><b>Create the message here<b></h4>
<br>
<form method='GET'>
    
    <textarea id="w3review" name="sms" rows="7" cols="70" value="{{request.GET.q}}">

    </textarea>
<br>
<br>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'p-sms' %}"><i
class="nav-icon fas fa-sms"></i> Send</a>
        
</form>      
    
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: instead of <a> you have to use <submit> or <button type="submit"> tag

Comment: Thank you,, I had not seen that. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

this worked.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="send_sms" name="submit">Send</button>
```